# Preparing strings to be passed into API query (escaping special characters)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I've run into some difficulties with strings and the Fetch API. I've got a React component that accepts a string, sets it to a variable and then constructs a query variable I can pass into `fetch()`.

The problem is accounting for special characters causing a 404 response. Here are some examples of strings I'm working with, and their desired output.

```
INPUT >>> DESIRED OUTPUT

Something's going on here >>> somethings-going-on-here

Dungeons & dragons >>> dungeons-%26-dragons

It's happening, right here >>> its-happening-right-here
```

I have the following regex, but it's not quite there yet (it's missing converting the `&` to `%26`)

```js
replace(/,?\s+/g, '-')
```

I had looked at using `encodeURIComponent` function but it doesn't seem to account for single quotes, which is how I landed up on regex.

Comment: I think you can use  string interpolation or `\``\` (backticks)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

```js
var params = new URLSearchParams();
params.set('param1',`Something's going on here`);
params.toString();
```

You can also use a library that takes care of it for you:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string
https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs